# Batch rename files by inserting a quote before the last character of a regex pattern

Tags: bash, rename, batch-processing

**01 - The situation**

Let's say I have hundreds of files like these:
(don't care about the file type)

```
Steven Scott - Stevens Dinner With Sandy.txt
Matt Lang - Matts First Song.txt
Martin Julien - Martins First Trip to Paris.txt
```

I want to batch rename them to get this output:

```
Steven Scott - Steven's Dinner With Sandy.txt
Matt Lang - Matt's First Song.txt
Martin Julien - Martin's First Trip to Paris.txt
```

**02 - What i did**

I first went to "regexr.com" to write my command.
I've matched my pattern with this expression:
 `(( - )(\w+))(?=(s))`

Here's the screenshot [image: Perfect match I need that excludes the "s".]

The substitution seems very simple to me:

`$1'`

And still on "regexr.com", I got what I wanted:

Screenshot #2:
[image: Good result]

Finally I executed the command into a test folder, which once again seems very basic.

`rename -vf "s/(( - )(\w+))(?=(s))/$1'/gi" *`

This is where I stop understanding what happened... Here's the output:

`Martin Julien's First Trip to Paris.txt Matt Lang's First Song.txt Steven Scott's Dinner With Sandy.txt`

Can anyone tell me what happened or if I made a mistake?

Thanks for your insights...
Martin

Comment: As below, but for futher debugging, I assume `-v` is for `verbose` and surprized you didn't get a clue of feedback from `rename`. But also use the `shell`'s debug feature; wrap your command like `set -vx ; my command .... ; set +vx` (better that each are on separate lines). to see what command has been read, then a line with the `+` char debug prompt, you'll see how any substitutions for env vars have been handled. Also the shell "normalizes" the quoting all strings, soe `set -vx; echo "Test Hello"; set +vx` will display `+ echo 'Test Hello'` as well as the "real" output. IHTH. Good luck.

Comment: Personal opinion: Don't bother. Filenames with valid typographical characters/punctuation marks, (other than hyphens and underscores), should be avoided.

Comment: What should the output of `Chris Scott - Chris Went To Work.txt` be?

Comment: @Ed Morton The exact same thing. I first put the files in a separate folder so they all have the same issue.

Comment: You want the output to be `Chris Scott - Chri's Went To Work.txt`? That seems like you'd be making it less legible rather than more legible.

Comment: @Ed Morton No, no, no! Haha. That file would keep the same name. Before executing the command, I separate the files that all have the same problem. A file like this would not be placed in the folder where I do the batch rename. Just to be clearer. But yes, you're right, that would be weird haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplified regex is more readable :

```
rename -v -f "s/( - \w+)(?=s)/\$1'/gi" *
```

Comment: Many thanks for that. I've always thought that characters like:
\w or \s etc. should be enclosed in brackets. Would it still work if I did:
`( - \w{1,10})` ?

Comment: Yes `( - \w{1,10})` should work.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` within double quotes will be expanded (probably to nothing) so your pattern in rename is actually `s/(( - )(\w+))(?=(s))/'/gi` - in other words you're not actually keeping the capture group.

You need to add an escape to prevent this expansion: `rename -vf "s/(( - )(\w+))(?=(s))/\$1'/gi" *`

Comment: A simple escape haha. Now that I see it, it becomes oubvious! Many thanks!